# c# Merge List with another List based on key

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge

My main object is a list of customers.  Because of the way I have to obtain the data I have two lists I need to merge as shown below.  The balances list includes the balances for all customers.  Basically I want to add the balances associated with a particular customer to the customers list.  I'm trying to use Linq to merge the two based on their common key of CustomerNumber, but haven't been able to make it work.

```
List<Customer> customers
List<Balance> balances

public class Customer
{
     int CustomerNumber {get;set;}
     List<Balance> Balances{get;set;}
}

public class Balance
{
     int CustomerNumber {get;set;}
     decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

So lets save I have this list of customers

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>{
new Customer {CustomerNumber = 1},
new Customer {CustomerNumber = 2},
new Customer {CustomerNumber = 3}
};
```

And this list of balances

```
List<Balance> balances = new List<Balance>{
new Balance {Amount = 10, CustomerNumber = 1},
new Balance {Amount = 20, CustomerNumber = 1},
new Balance {Amount = 30, CustomerNumber = 2},
new Balance {Amount = 80, CustomerNumber = 2},
new Balance {Amount = 100, CustomerNumber = 2},
new Balance {Amount = 50, CustomerNumber = 3},
};
```

In the end I would have

- Customer 1 would have a list with the **10** and **20** amounts
- Customer 2 would have a list with the **30**, **80**, and **100** amounts
- Customer 3 would have a list with the **50** amount.

The current solution looks like:

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    var matchingBalances = balances
                     .Where(x => x.CustomerNumber == customer.CustomerNumber);
    customer.Balances.AddRange(matchingBalances);
}
```

**Update**: Here's what I ended up using.

```
var merge2 = customers.GroupJoin(balances,
        c => c.CustomerNumber,
        b => b.CustomerNumber,
        (c, b) =>
        {                
            c.Balances = b.ToList()
            return c;
        });
```

Comment: Well that sounds like a join - so what have you *tried* - and what are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: I see you commented on @KevinOwens answer that you are using that solution, which is in my estimation a fine way to handle that.  If you are looking to optimize an existing function, you should put what you are already using and what what ways specifically you are looking to optimize, faster processing, lower memory footprint etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  My next post will be better!

Comment: I posted a `GroupJoin` solution below too, this might also help.

Comment: It is bad practice to have side effect in the LINQ.

Comment: Based on my quick research this is the line c.Balances = b.ToList()?  Any suggestions on how I can do this without a side effect?

Comment: Instead of returning, use the result from merge2 variable. Look at my post below on how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `GroupJoin` a try...

This will sum the Amounts...

```
var merge = customers.GroupJoin(balances, 
            c => c.CustomerNumber, 
            b => b.CustomerNumber,
            (c, b) => new
            {
                custname = c.CustomerNumber, 
                custamount = b.Sum(b2 => b2.Amount)
            });

            foreach (var cust in merge)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cust.custname, cust.custamount);
            }
```

The below will list them out....

```
        var merge2 = customers.GroupJoin(balances,
            c => c.CustomerNumber,
            b => b.CustomerNumber,
            (c, b) => new
            {
                custname = c.CustomerNumber,
                custamount = b.ToList()
            });

        foreach (var cust in merge2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} has following amounts: ", 
                cust.custname);

            foreach (var amount in cust.custamount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(amount.Amount);
            }
        }
```

The image shows the output.

[image]

Comment: I ended up using a combination of this and Toons33 solution.  I'll update the OP.

Comment: @mmeyer That's essentially what I posted here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    var matchingBalances = balances.Where(x => x.CustomerNumber == customer.CustomerNumber);
    customer.Balances.AddRange(matchingBalances);
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently, and I'm looking for a more efficient method of linking the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
var combined = from c in customers
               join b in balance on b.CustomerNumber equal c.CustomerNumber
               select new{
                   Amount = b.Amount,
                   Balance = c.Balance,
                   };
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but this doesn't produce the desired results.